# printing a float has unexpected value

Tags: c++, io, floating-point, precision

Why has '32' been added to the value of v in the output below?

```
int main()
{
    float v = 9.999e8;

    std::cout << "v --> " << v << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::cout << "v --> " << v << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
v --> 9.999e+08
v --> 999900032.000000
             ^^
```

Is it an artefact of printing the value, or that 9.999e+08 cannot be accurately represented in a float?

Changing v to a double resolves the issue but I want to understand the actual cause.

**strong text**

Comment: What they said.  Try using a `double` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the common desktop implementation of `float`, the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), there are only 24 significand bits (and 8 exponent bits). This means that the biggest consecutive value that can be represented, without precision loss, is 2<sup>24</sup> which is approximately 1.6E7 (1.6•10<sup>7</sup>). For example, an odd value above this threshold can't be represented accurately by such a `float`, since the least significant 1-bit "falls off" the representation.

Your value is approximately 1E9 (10<sup>9</sup>), which is 60 times larger. It means that the  value can be about 30 off (after rounding to the nearest representable value). Note that the exponent bits contribute 2<sup>exp</sup> (sans the nitpicking about the offset thing), and not 10<sup>exp</sup>.

With `double` there are 53 bits, which are more than enough for 1E9 (10<sup>9</sup>).

Comment: @EricPostpischil good catch. Fixed and clarified.

Answer (score 2):

This is the nature of finite precision math. If you try to store a value that can't be represented exactly, at best you'll get the closest representable value.

Have a look at the binary:
999900032 -> 111011100110010100001110000000
999900000 -> 11101110011001010000110**11**00000

So representing this number exactly would require two additional bits of precision. Presumably, that's more than `float` provides on your system.